# Is there any way to crawl a website with POST form?

Tags: python, html, forms, post, web-crawler

I am using Python 3 and crawling some websites.

As long as the form is in GET, I can easily parse the link. Is there any workaround to automatically download the HTML produced after clicking a form that has *action=POST*? (Mr Google does not tell anything valuable about it...)

Thanks

Comment: what libraries are you using? it will be better if you paste code snippet of yours.

Comment: I am using Django. Have no snippet. I am planning to crawl this POST (but dont know how).

Comment: My Python framework is Django. I do not have any code example I am using because I do not use anything yet. I want to know how can I do it because I am not sure it is possible. Thanks

Comment: django is a web framework. its not related with crawling and scraping. If you haven't tried anything yet, then try it. Do some research by yourself before posting a vague question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the scraper framework Scrapy. It allows scraping by using POST requests. Although Scrapy can be used in Python2 (so far).

There is [an example on how to scrape using POST requests](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-usage-examples) in the Scrapy documentation.

If your scraping job is easy you can use the [Requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). It allows POST calls in this way:

```
import requests
r = requests.post("http://web-address.com", {'parameter': 'value'})
r.text
```

Comment: Thanks, I will see what it is